# Jquery adding image URLs from Firebase database into HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, firebase

I am trying to insert images from a storage platform (Firebase in this case) in a HTML table. I am using a database which has links to each image (see snapshot at the end of the post) and so far, I have managed to insert only the text from the database in the table and one image, but not the rest, as one can see in this screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the text is shown, while the images have that small icon instead. The code is shown below. It works very well in my browser, but for some reason, it doesn't show in SE platform. Can anyone help me figure out what am I doing wrong? How can I make the images appear in that table?

```html
<html>
<body>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCg9wsEL5tAYdSyz9IapqvvMGWpFNAlc74",
    authDomain: "checkup-7b62e.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://checkup-7b62e.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "checkup-7b62e",
    storageBucket: "checkup-7b62e.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "324802643995"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script>
// '.tbl-content' consumed little space for vertical scrollbar, scrollbar width depend on browser/os/platfrom. Here calculate the scollbar width .
$(window).on("load resize ", function() {
  var scrollWidth = $('.tbl-content').width() - $('.tbl-content table').width();
  $('.tbl-header').css({'padding-right':scrollWidth});
}).resize();
</script>
<head>
    <title>Evenimente locale</title>
    </head>
<table style="width:100%" id="ex-table">
  <tr id="tr">
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Categoria</th>

 </table> 


<script>
    var anunturi = firebase.database();
    var storage = firebase.storage();

    anunturi.ref("-Events").orderByKey().limitToLast(5).once('value', function(snapshot){
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            var content = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                var val = data.val();
              var link = val.imageUrl;                
              var storageRef = storage.refFromURL(link).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                 var test = url;
                 document.querySelector('img').src = test;  
             }).catch(function(error) {});   
                alert(val.imageUrl);
                content +='<tr>';
                content += '<td>' + '<img src={val.imageUrl} border={0} height={150} width={150}></img>' + '</td>';
                content += '<td>' + val.categoria + '</td>';

              });
            $('#ex-table').append(content);
                
  //var tbody = $('table tbody');
   //   tbody.html($('tr',tbody).get().reverse());
        }
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The database looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your API key. Here comes the random traffic.

Comment: That's fine. It's for testing only anyways

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane The API key is public information.

Comment: Log this out, see what you get: document.querySelector('img').src = test;

Comment: Thanks! How do I do that? console.log(test)?